# OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, steam

Running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on an Athlon II X4 631 with 4GB DDR3 and a GTX 285.

I've tried all the solutions listed in various different forums including here and none of them seem to work. The command line fixes all return a "file" not found error. And if I try it without sudo I get "permission denied" instead.

I would just do what I did last-time and switch to the 32bit Release of Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS but that release doesn't even correctly boot, and when it does only the mouse loads and  then it crashes.

Comment: And the command glxinfo ends up showing a huge list (too large to copy-paste or screenshot)  every line is  "none" and "slow". 
So perhaps it's a driver issue........ugh